# compress json data from rest node.js use express compression

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, compression

I created a small application rest node.js. I try to compress data json, which return by request api, but nothing compressed. Use express and compression.

```
var express = require('express');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var compression = require('compression');

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(serveStatic('public', {'index': ['index.html']}));
app.use('/', require('./routes'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});

app.disable('x-powered-by');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
});
```

this response header without compession =(((

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3756
ETag: W/"56IqvwOVCBB3MRndvDsFTA=="
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 14:21:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Help.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using plain curl to request it? Tell curl to ask for compressed data:

```
$ curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' -v -o tmp http://localhost:3000/
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< ETag: W/"qIOLMe2deSCB3/8ol7nulg=="
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Encoding: gzip # <========================================== !!!
< Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 16:14:50 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Now the download is gzipped.

Comment: This approach involves send in request 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate'. But client should not be send 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' - like server compression on iis or apache output compression.  How to code this on node.js

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, but I believe the client *has* to tell the server "Hey, I can accept compressed output" before the server compresses it. If it was any other way, webservers might send compressed content to clients who aren't capable of it. But it may be possible that the default IIS/Apache configurations default to compression even if the client didn't ask for it…? But Node's HTTP/Express servers don't seem to do that.

Comment: @AhmedFasih is right, the client has to request for gzip response